# Submit form and show result in a new window depending on which submit button I clicked

Tags: html

I have a form for adding new article. And I have 2 submit buttons:

```
<button type="submit" name="action" value="add">Add</button>
<button type="submit" name="action" value="preview">Preview</button>
```

Both buttons belongs to the same form. When I click add I want the new page ("Your article has been successfully added") to be shown in the same tab, when I click "preview" I want to open new tab.

I know that I can set `target="blank"` in `<form>` tag but it will affect both buttons, but how to distinguish them? Preferably without using JS (like making 2 forms with doubling data or kind of...)

Answer (score 0):

If you have no problem to ahead with Javascript, Please try it. Else ignore it.

```
<form id="formElement">
<button type="submit" name="action" value="add">Add</button>
<button type="submit" name="action" value="preview" onclick="newPage();">Preview</button>
</form>
```

script

```
    function newPage(){
        $('#formElement').attr('target','_blank');
    }
```